How to save image of map when using custom basemap tile provider plugins?
I am using Leaflet v1.9.4.  I would like to be able to save an image of the current map, and am attempting to use a plugin, leaflet-image (https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-image).
For map tiles, I am using either azure-maps-leaflet (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-maps-leaflet) or leaflet-bing-layer (https://github.com/digidem/leaflet-bing-layer) tile layer plugins, but am experiencing the same behavior with both.
The issue I am seeing is when I try and create map image, I get a map tile URL error about an invalid URL.  But only if I use one of the map tile providers.  If I use leaflet with a map tile URL and the native TileLayer, the image plugin works correctly.  But if I swap in and use either tile provider plugin, I see the requested URLs for tiles don't have things like the subdomain string replaced in, or my credential key included, etc.
I think I've tracked this down to the leaflet-image plugin makes as call to the TileLayer.getTileUrl function.  In both providers, this function doesn't appear to actually be returning the correct URL for the tile, and is missing things like constructing the correct URL containing all the string replacements that are used when building a tile URL.
I think part of my issue is I'm not sure where the problem I'm having lives - it looks like some sort of incompatibility between the snapshot plugin and the custom tile layer plugins, and I'm happy to poke at trying to customize or filing a bug on their respective projects, but I don't know which one is misbehaving.
My hunch is that either the leaflet-image plugin is taking advantage of getTileUrl which works for native TileLayers with embedded URLs but not for third party basemap providers, and it just happens to work in most cases.  But that getTileUrl inside custom TileLayer providers wasn't intended to be exposed and used like that.  Or that the custom basemap providers aren't implementing getTileUrl in a way to actually return a fully working URL.  Which maybe that could be, but it seemed strange both providers I've tried, neither work correctly.
Apologies for not being a straight-up programming question, either, Leaflet github points to here for support questions!
